# Where clause sometimes filter NULL values but sometimes don't

Tags: sql-server-2008, null, where-clause

Can somebody explain me why I have two different results with those two similar queries, please?

Example:

```
-- Create table t1 and insert values.
CREATE TABLE t1 (a NVARCHAR(4) NULL)
INSERT INTO t1 values (NULL)
INSERT INTO t1 values ('0')
INSERT INTO t1 values ('1')
GO

PRINT 'Testing NULL values'
DECLARE @varname NVARCHAR(4)
SET @varname = '1'

SELECT * 
FROM t1 
WHERE a <> @varname

SELECT * 
FROM t1 
WHERE a <> '1'
GO

-- Drop table t1.
DROP TABLE t1
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by different *results*?

Comment: I get the same one row result (`0`) with both queries. (as I'd expect)

Comment: Me too. Thought it was a Null <> Null question at first

Comment: Try to set ansi nulls to off.

Comment: If you SET ANSI_NULLS OFF before executing the first SELECT, I will have 2 different results.
And for me, the first one is the good, or at least is the result that I expect.
So, in my source table I have 3 values (NULL, 0 and 1), and I want all values different of '1' (NULL and 0).
The first one gives me that result but the second one just gives me '0' and ignores the NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I get a different result if set ansi nulls off is used than if the ansi nulls are on.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
When the ansi nulls it's on you have the same result on both queries, and when it's off you have different results.
For me, I should get the same result when it's off.

For example, when it's off I wanted to get this:
Result 1 and 2 -> NULL and 0
In another words, I wanted to get all the values different of '1'.

Comment: Then you need ansi nulls on or you need to specifically include the nulls in your code.

Comment: The ansi nulls on don't work for me because that exclude the NULL value and I know I can put in the WHERE clause "t1.a <> '1' or t1.a IS NULL" but I think that is not a solution, is just an workaround.
I want to write "WHERE t1.a <> '1'" and have the NULL also as result.

But the principal reason that I wrote in this forum was because I don't know why "WHERE t1.a <> '1'" returns a different result then "WHERE t1.a <> @varname" (using ANSI_NULLS OFF).